# Game class frame event handling lost when combined with initial UI starting frame

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatching

i 'm developing a java game for my college project. the game consists of a UI (for selecting Play / How To / Highscores etc) and the Game itself. The UI and the Game run perfectly separately, but i'm having trouble combining them. Although, i've been able to combine the two. but when the game is accessed through the UI, the game loses all event-handling (and thus is stuck on "press spacebar to proceed")

Examine the following pieces of codes and please help:

**this is the Game class (draws and displays the game)**

```
package AllPanels;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class BailoutGame extends Core implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("inside main");
        new BailoutGame().run();
        System.out.println("outside main");
    }
    private Image map,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,scope,background,stopwatch,hitmarker,shot;
    int x=329,y=30,escapePressCount, xShot,yShot,xMarker,yMarker,xBullet,yBullet,xTargetMedian,yTargetMedian,xMarkerMedian,yMarkerMedian;
    int totalBullets=15,bulletsCounter,bulletsLeft,killCounter=1,targetShotCounter=3;
    private boolean spaceBar,escapePressed,t1Shot;
    String msg="",space="Press Space-Bar To Start";

    @Override
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("inside game init");
        super.init();
        Window w = s.getFullScreenWindow();
        w.addKeyListener(this);
        w.addMouseListener(this);
        w.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        System.out.println("outside game init");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);     
        Window w = s.getFullScreenWindow();
        map = new ImageIcon("/home/vivek/Projects/Java/GameRenderingTest/src/ImagesFolder/Map.png").getImage();
        scope = new ImageIcon("/home/vivek/Projects/Java/GameRenderingTest/src/ImagesFolder/Sniper Scope.png").getImage();
        t1 = new ImageIcon("/home/vivek/Projects/Java/GameRenderingTest/src/ImagesFolder/Target 1.png").getImage();
        t2 = new ImageIcon("/home/vivek/Projects/Java/GameRenderingTest/src/ImagesFolder/t2.png").getImage();
        background = new ImageIcon("/home/vivek/Projects/Java/GameRenderingTest/src/ImagesFolder/background.png").getImage();
        stopwatch = new ImageIcon("/home/vivek/Projects/Java/GameRenderingTest/src/ImagesFolder/Stopwatch.png").getImage();
        hitmarker = new ImageIcon("/home/vivek/Projects/Java/GameRenderingTest/src/ImagesFolder/HitMarker.png").getImage();
        shot = new ImageIcon("/home/vivek/Projects/Java/GameRenderingTest/src/ImagesFolder/Shot.png").getImage();

        g.drawImage(map, 0, 0, null);
        if(t1Shot == false){
            g.drawImage(t1,247,255,null);
        }
        g.drawImage(scope, x-1366,y-768,null);
        g.drawImage(stopwatch,1366-200,25,null);
        g.drawImage(hitmarker,-7,409,null);
        g.setColor(w.getForeground());
        g.drawString(PointSystem.displayPoints,50,50);
        if(spaceBar){
            g.drawString(GameTimer.time, 1250, 125);
        }
        if(t1Shot){
            if(PointSystem.headshot){
                xMarkerMedian = (62 + 124) / 2;
                yMarkerMedian = (426 + 530) / 2;
            }
            if(PointSystem.bodyshot){
                xMarkerMedian = (2 + 184) / 2;
                yMarkerMedian = (530 + 766) / 2;
            }
            g.drawImage(shot,xMarkerMedian+xMarker,yMarkerMedian+yMarker,null);
        }
        if(spaceBar == false ){
            g.setColor(w.getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1366, 768);
            g.setColor(w.getForeground());
            g.drawString(space, 550, 500);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
        PointSystem.headshot = false;
        PointSystem.bodyshot = false;
        xShot = e.getX();
        yShot = e.getY();
        bulletsCounter++;
        bulletsManager(bulletsCounter);
        if((xShot >= 237) && (yShot >=247) && (xShot <= 282) && (yShot <= 298)){
            target1(xShot,yShot);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            stop();
            if((escapePressCount % 2) != 0 && escapePressCount != 0 )
                escapePressed = true;
            else
                escapePressed = false;

            escapePressCount++;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            GameTimer.watchStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            GameTimer.chronometer.start();
            spaceBar = true;
        }
    }

    public void target1(int xShot, int yShot) {

            }
        }
        PointSystem.TotalPoint(targetShotCounter);
    }

    public void bulletsManager(int bulletsCounter) {
        bulletsLeft = totalBullets - bulletsCounter;
        if(bulletsLeft==0){
            //GameOver Dialog.
        }
    }
}
```

**the core Class (does all the back-end work).**

```
package AllPanels;

import java.awt.*;

public class Core {

    private static final DisplayMode modes[] = {
        new DisplayMode(800,600,32,0),
        new DisplayMode(800,600,24,0),
        new DisplayMode(800,600,16,0),
        new DisplayMode(1366,768,32,0),
        new DisplayMode(1366,768,24,0),
        new DisplayMode(1366,768,16,0),
    };
    private boolean running;
    protected ScreenManager s;

    public void stop(){
        running = false;
    }


    public void run(){
        System.out.println("inside run");
        try{
            init();
            gameLoop();
        }finally{
            s.restoreScreen();
        }
        System.out.println("outside run");
    }

    public void init(){
        System.out.println("inside Core init");
        s = new ScreenManager();
        DisplayMode dm = s.findFirstCompatibleMode(modes);
        s.setFullScreen(dm);               
        Window w = s.getFullScreenWindow();
        w.setFont(new Font("ubuntu",Font.PLAIN,20));
        w.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        w.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        running = true;       

        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image cursorImage = toolkit.getImage("Scope.png");
        Point cursorHotSpot = new Point(0,0);
        Cursor customCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(cursorImage, cursorHotSpot, "Cursor");
        w.setCursor(customCursor);

        GameTimer.watchStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("outside Core init");
    }

    public void gameLoop(){
        System.out.println("inside gameLoop");
        long startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long cumTime = startingTime;
        while(running){
            long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - cumTime;
            cumTime += timePassed;
            update(timePassed);
            Graphics2D g = s.getGraphics();
            draw(g);
            g.dispose();
            s.update();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
        System.out.println("outside gameLoop");
    }

    public void update(long timePassed) {}

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {};
}
```

**and the last piece of code: this is the panel in UI Frame from which i need to access the Game**

```
package AllPanels;

import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class LoadingPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener  {
     public static Task task;

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
            loadingBar.setValue(progress);
        } 
    } 
     public class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            Random random = new Random();
            setProgress(0);
            for(int progress=0;progress<=100;progress++) {
                if(progress==2){
                    loadingLabel.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else if(progress==4){
                    detailsLabel.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else if(progress==7){
                    nameLabel.setText(""+MainFrame.playerName.toUpperCase());
                    nameLabel.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else if(progress==10){
                    if(AllPanels.MapPanel.mapNumber==1){
                        aoLabel.setText("BAILOUT");
                    }
                    aoLabel.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else if(progress==13){
                    missionLabel.setText("Find and Eliminate the 5 targets silently");
                    missionLabel.setEnabled(true);                           
                }
                else if(progress==16){
                    etaLabel.setText("03:00 Minutes");
                    etaLabel.setEnabled(true);   
                    loadingLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading Objects.png")));
                }
                else if(progress==31){
                    loadingLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading Shadows.png")));
                }
                else if(progress==46){
                    loadingLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading Sounds.png")));
                }
                else if(progress==61){
                    loadingLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading Targets.png")));
                }
                else if(progress==71){
                    loadingLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading AI.png")));
                }
                else if(progress==91){
                    loadingLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading Weapons.png")));
                }
                else if(progress==100){
                    loadingLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Done.png")));
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(500));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
            }
            return null;
        }
        public void done(){
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            startGameButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public LoadingPanel() {
        initComponents();      
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        loadingBarCoverLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        loadingBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        loadingStartButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        detailsLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        detailsCoverLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        nameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        aoLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        missionLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        etaLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        loadingLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        startGameButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        bgLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        loadingBarCoverLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Progress Bar Cover.png"))); 
        add(loadingBarCoverLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(25, 300, 820, 30));

        loadingBar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        loadingBar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("BankGothic Md BT", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        loadingBar.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(51, 153, 255), 2));
        loadingBar.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        loadingBar.setStringPainted(true);
        add(loadingBar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(25, 300, 820, 30));

        loadingStartButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Start Off.png"))); 
        loadingStartButton.setBorder(null);
        loadingStartButton.setDisabledIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Start Disabled.png"))); 
        loadingStartButton.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Start Pressed.png"))); 
        loadingStartButton.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Start On.png")));
        loadingStartButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                loadingStartButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        add(loadingStartButton, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(475, 20, 125, 40));

        detailsLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Details.png"))); 
        detailsLabel.setDisabledIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Details disabled.png"))); 
        detailsLabel.setEnabled(false);
        add(detailsLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(15, 90, 185, 170));
        detailsLabel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");

        detailsCoverLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Text Cover.png"))); 
        add(detailsCoverLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 90, 800, 170));

        nameLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("BankGothic Md BT", 0, 30));
        nameLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 191, 211));
        nameLabel.setEnabled(false);
        nameLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);
        add(nameLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 85, 800, 40));

        aoLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("BankGothic Md BT", 0, 30)); 
        aoLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 191, 211));
        aoLabel.setToolTipText("");
        aoLabel.setEnabled(false);
        add(aoLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 130, 800, 40));

        missionLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("BankGothic Md BT", 0, 30)); 
        missionLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 191, 211));
        missionLabel.setEnabled(false);
        add(missionLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 175, 800, 40));

        etaLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("BankGothic Md BT", 0, 30)); 
        etaLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 191, 211));
        add(etaLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 220, 800, 40));

        loadingLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading Buildings.png"))); 
        loadingLabel.setDisabledIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading Disabled.png")));
        loadingLabel.setEnabled(false);
        add(loadingLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(475, 260, 385, 40));

        startGameButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/StartGame Off.png"))); 
        startGameButton.setDisabledIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/StartGame Disabled.png"))); 
        startGameButton.setEnabled(false);
        startGameButton.setOpaque(false);
        startGameButton.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/StartGame Pressed.png"))); 
        startGameButton.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/StartGame On.png"))); 
        startGameButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                startGameButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        add(startGameButton, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(860, 20, 140, 70));

        bgLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/UserInterface/Loading Panel/Loading Page.png")));
        add(bgLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, -1, -1));
    }                       

    private void loadingStartButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        this.remove(loadingBarCoverLabel);
        MainFrame.backButton.setEnabled(false);
        loadingStartButton.setEnabled(false);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        task = new Task();
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        task.execute();
    }                                                  

    private void startGameButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        if(MapPanel.mapNumber==1){
            new BailoutGame().run();
        }
    }                                                          
    public static javax.swing.JLabel aoLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel bgLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel detailsCoverLabel;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel detailsLabel;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel etaLabel;
    public static javax.swing.JProgressBar loadingBar;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel loadingBarCoverLabel;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel loadingLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton loadingStartButton;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel missionLabel;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel nameLabel;
    public static javax.swing.JButton startGameButton;               
}
```

Comment: Scanning through the source, I was looking for where you were having multiple threads and do not see it, though I may have missed that part.  However the symptoms you describe is a classic behavior in which an application that requires multiple threads is instead single threaded so the thread execution is being stopped from some action such as when polling a device or reading input from some source.

Comment: It really looks to me like Core should be extending Thread.  Take a look at this article on concurrency and multi-threading.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: thanks Richard. threading did it. it was silly of me not to see it. THANKS anyways!!

Comment: beware: your swingworker implementation is incorrect - you _must not_ access swing components in doInBackground() !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanning through the source, I was looking for where you were having multiple threads and do not see it, though I may have missed that part. However the symptoms you describe is a classic behavior in which an application that requires multiple threads is instead single threaded so the thread execution is being stopped from some action such as when polling a device or reading input from some source.

It really looks to me like Core should be extending Thread. Take a look at this [article on concurrency and multi-threading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency).